# firestore: Query Multiple Search Term With Map Not working as Expected

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Scenario**

I am having a collection of courses I want to search collection based on user input comma separated terms. However, when executing the query all courses collection is returned.

**Code Snippet in Flutter**

```dart
    Future<void> search(List<String> keywords) async {
        var docs = coursesRef;
        // BELOW I ITERATE OVER KEYWORDS CONVERT
        // THEM TO LOWER CASE AND APPEND TERM TO MAP searchTerms
        keywords.forEach((word) {
          String term = word.trim().toLowerCase();
          docs.where('searchTerms.$term', isEqualTo: true);
        });
        docs.where('isDraft', isEqualTo: false);

        QuerySnapshot query = await docs.getDocuments();

        courses = [];
        query.documents.forEach((doc) {
          Course course = Course.fromDoc(doc);
          courses.add(course);
        });

        notifyListeners();
      }
```

**My map field shown below:**

[image]

**The Search Result Returned**

Is all current courses collection shown below:

```js
    {uid: 3riP6kUweNPF2EV7avD2, name: Chemistry, code: CHEM208, academy: American University of Beirut, academyCode: AUB, isDraft: false, keywords: [chem208, chem 208, chemistry]}
    {uid: KyyTpfEbbG8FhJbKvsuo, name: Math, code: MATH204, academy: American University of Beirut, academyCode: AUB, isDraft: false, keywords: [math204, math 204, math]}
    {uid: jTBaY0T2CHPUGKPg8tb8, name: Chemistry, code: CHEM200, academy: American University of Beirut, academyCode: AUB, isDraft: false, keywords: [chem200, chem 200, chemistry]}
    {uid: vcdLCmrwN4RPKDt7CeUX, name: Accounting, code: ACC 213, academy: American University of Beirut, academyCode: AUB, isDraft: false, keywords: [accounting, acc213, acc 213]}
```

**Given**

Keywords only contains term **math**

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `where(...)` it returns a new `Query` object. So you'll need to update your variable with the new query each time you add a condition:

```
var docs = coursesRef;
keywords.forEach((word) {
  String term = word.trim().toLowerCase();
  docs = docs.where('searchTerms.$term', isEqualTo: true);
});
docs = docs.where('isDraft', isEqualTo: false);
```

Comment: Thanks Frank for your answer. It works, however searchTerms multiples only work on single document for example if I am searching for ```math,accounting``` I get no results. I presume this is limitation by cloud firestore, on the other hand if I search for ```math, math204``` I get single record which is expected. Is my assumption correct or I am doing something wrong? Thanks.